# Looking for DEM, DTM, DSM for northern England

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I'm looking for DEM or similar (DSM, DTM) from which to make a slope map to identify suitable paragliding hills in an area of northern England - the Yorkshire Dales.

I would like to be able to resolve cliffs over 10m, so the higher the resolution the better.

Answer (score 1):

Your best source of data for the UK is [data.gov.uk](https://data.gov.uk/search?q=elevation&filters%5Bpublisher%5D=&filters%5Btopic%5D=&filters%5Bformat%5D=&sort=best).

- [LIDAR DSM Time Stamped Tiles updated 17 June 2019](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/d65c3dc2-56fb-4147-bca4-45dc78889ffc/lidar-dsm-time-stamped-tiles)

  > The LIDAR DSM (Digital Surface Model) Time Stamped Tiles product is an archive of raster elevation data produced by the Environment Agency. Site specific surveys have been carried out across England since 1998, with certain areas, such as the coastal zone, being surveyed multiple times.
- [LIDAR DSM Time Stamped Tiles updated 08 August 2019](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/8275e71e-1516-42a1-bb0c-4fa73807fe2b/lidar-dtm-time-stamped-tiles)
- [LIDAR Composite DTM - 2m](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/002d24f0-0056-4176-b55e-171ba7f0e0d5/lidar-composite-dtm-2m)

  > The LIDAR Composite DTM (Digital Terrain Model) is a raster elevation model covering ~75% of England at 2m spatial resolution.
- [LIDAR Composite DTM - 1m](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/80c522cc-e0bf-4466-8409-57a04c456197/lidar-composite-dsm-1m)
- [LIDAR Composite DTM - 50cm](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/0ab507af-cd91-40cb-8524-3efafc267211/lidar-composite-dsm-50cm)
- [LIDAR Composite DTM - 25cm](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/8b007edd-a886-44ca-9fa0-2ee2efc1248d/lidar-composite-dsm-25cm)
- [National LIDAR Programme](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/f0db0249-f17b-4036-9e65-309148c97ce4/national-lidar-programme) will have updated elevation data by 2021. You can see a map of which areas have been surveyed so far [here](https://environment.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=11a8edc1c1d341379c857bf3d3806e4b). The Yorkshire Dales area is listed as "planned" with no target date specified.

  > The Environment Agency National LIDAR Programme aims to provide accurate elevation data at 1m spatial resolution for all of England by 2021.

Comment: It's worth adding that you can also download the entire UK dem from OS open data but that is at a coarser resolution of 50m.